# Recent Hotmail Update is crashing FireFox. Is there a fix available

Tags: firefox, hotmail, firebug

I have latest version of FireFox. It has always worked fine using HOTMAIL until recently. I check a checkbox on my items list and FireFox chokes. Thinking back it seems to have started after a recent FireBug update so that may be related. I am liking the older version of Firebug better by the way but thats another post alltogether. Is anyone else having this problem? Is there a fix available?

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: You could uninstall firebug and find an old version somewhere. Or just not use hotmail. Either way this is not a programing question.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Tools->Add-Ons menu and disable all extensions.  Go to hotmail and see if it works.  If it does, then you know that FF is not what is causing the issue.  If you suspect that Firebug is the issue, you can specifically disable that extension first and try.

If it is indeed Firebug, you can set a list of sites in Firebug that it should ignore.  It is under the Firebug options in Tools->Add-Ons.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Firefox are you using? We had some reports of this after 3.5 was released, and upgrading to 3.5 seemed to have fixed it for most of the users I've talked with. I've never tacked it down to a particular add on, but if you follow Rebthor's advice and figure which add on it is I'd apprecaite the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by Chrome Firebug... after looking at Crash reports for myself. So the Chrome version of Firebug does infect the Firefox version and isn't isolated within Chrome itself?